# Range.value = Range.value?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to understand an Excel spreadsheet I was recently sent, which includes this VBA code:

```
Range("name_1").Value = Range("name_1").Value
```

(same name btw)

What's the purpose of this code? And it's repeated for many names (names 1 through 12, all of them have important purposes in the model)

Thanks!

Comment: It's the equivalent of copying and pasting special values only (but more efficient).

Comment: Which effectively means any formulas will be replaced with values

Comment: I understand, thanks!